# ant release fail when ADT export works fine

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, adt, eclipse-adt

I'm currently trying to automate my application's build, but when it comes to the following command, it fails !

```
ant release
```

I don't understand where is the problem/ error that causes the crash, in fact, when I export my apk from ADT, it works just fine.

Here is the output of my console :

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Program Files\ADT\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:720: The following error occurred
while executing this line:
C:\Program Files\ADT\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the 
compiler error output for details.
```

First thing I would to know is : Where is this "compiler error output" ? Because I searched through my project but found nothing...

**EDIT**

I'd misread the console, all the [javac] log were above the "BUILD FAILED" line.
But still, it's not very clear :

```
[javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[javac] 22 errors
[javac] 53 warnings
```

What is -Xlint ? I read it only concern the warnings, it is true ?

22 Errors ? Really !? Why so much errors when it works flawlessly with ADT export ?

**END OF EDIT**

Second thing : please help me to find what goes wrong, I already made my automation script work for both iOS and windows phone, Android is the last barrier to a full success !

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution :

I use androidannotation and configure my ADT to work with it but I totally forgot to configure ANT to work with androidannotation.

I've just follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Building-Project-Ant) and now it works like a charm !